# How many right triangles can be built from points

Tags: geometry, triangles, python

There are array of points, I need to determine how many right-angled triangles can be built from them.

This is a task for both programming and geometry.

Because the number of points can be very large, and the time to run the program is limited.

Please tell me whether it is possible to somehow derive a formula to determine the number of possible triangles.

Input format:
The first line contains a single integer N - the number of points in the set
Next, N lines contain two integers: xi, yi

My code:

```
from math import sqrt

def f(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    a = [(x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2, (x3-x2)**2+(y3-y2)**2, (x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2]
    a.sort()
    if a[0]+a[1]==a[2]:
        return True
    return False 

N = int(input())
ar = []
for i in range(N):
    ar.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])

count = 0
for ia in range(N):
    for ib in range(N):
        for ic in range(N):
            if ia!=ib and ia!=ic and ib!=ic :
                a = ar[ia]; b = ar[ib]; c = ar[ic]
                if f(a[0],a[1],b[0],b[1],c[0],c[1]): 
                    count+=1
print(count//6)
```

my code goes beyond time limits

P.S. DSolved the problem using vectors, also does not pass in time

```
def f1(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
    a = [x2-x1,y2-y1]
    b = [x3-x2,y3-y2]
    if a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1] is 0:
        return True 
    return False

N = int(input())
ar = []
for i in range(N):
    ar.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])

count = 0
for ia in range(N):
    for ib in range(N):
        for ic in range(N):
            if ia!=ib and ia!=ic and ib!=ic :
                a = ar[ia]; b = ar[ib]; c = ar[ic]
                if f1(a[0],a[1],b[0],b[1],c[0],c[1]): 
                    count+=1 
print(count//2)
```

Beginning of implementation of the algorithm with polar angles:

```
from math import *

def polar(a,b):
    res = atan2(b,a)
    if (res < 0) :
      res += 2 * pi
    return res

N = int(input())
A = []

for i in range(N):
    A.append([int(j) for j in input().split()])

DS = []
for i in range(N):
    p = A[i]
    for j in range(N):
        if j!=i:
            D = [A[j][0]-p[0], A[j][1]-p[1]]
            ang = polar(D[0],D[1]) 
            DS.append(ang)

DS.sort()
#what's next?
```

Comment: One sketch is to consider the points in neighboring quarters (e.g. $I$ and $II$). For each point in quarter $I$, there can be only one point in quarter $II$, which will make right angle triangle with the origin as the third vertex...

Comment: I do not understand your logic, the points of the triangle may be in one quarter

Comment: Oh, yes, the two points in one quarter can also make right angle with each other. My sketch considered the right angle at the origin. Since, it is a programming problem, maybe set up Pythagorean theorem for all possible triples of points?

Comment: I added my code using the Pythagorean theorem

Comment: but it's too long. O(N^3)

Comment: Another idea is to use vectors, note that for perpendicular vectors, the dot product must be zero.

Comment: Solved the problem using vectors, also does not pass in time. (added code to the topic)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131880/the-amount-of-right-triangles-on-a-finite-square-rectangular-lattice. There is post related to this, though there's only an answer for the grid type $n$x$2$

Comment: As a coding-efficiency question, shouldn't this be posted to [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an $\mathcal{O}(N^2\log N)$-time algorithm, coming from an ability to compute, for each point $P$, the number of right angles at $P$, in $\mathcal{O}(N\log N)$ time. This can be done by considering the (other) points in the polar coordinate system with the origin at $P$, and sorting by polar angle, after which the counting is easy. (Actually there's no need to compute the polar angles - this is just an idea to be used *indirectly*.)

Comment: @yoloy: Basically, you're computing the intersection of two sets: the original array of points (with $P$ excluded), and its right-angle-rotated copy, both sorted. (Again, it is not needed to make an actual copy; it can be generated on the fly.) The intersection is computed in linear time - so it is the *sorting* that consumes the most of.

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not fully understand. What intersections should I look for. I added the beginning of your algorithm code to the topic

Answer (score 0):

The answer is dependent on the position of the points. So I think Brute force method is the only way, i.e you will have to consider various combinations of triplets of points. So no, I don't think you will be able to use any simple formula to solve the problem. But using nested loops this can be solved fairly easily.

Comment: I tried it does not work. Not enough time

Comment: @yoloy will a c++ code do?